# How to check if whole program is flashed on ARM?

Tags: c, flash, arm, embedded

I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc 5.3 to produce binaries for STM32L4. I'm using bootloader to flash program. Problem is I can't be sure if I'm flashing whole file. I don't have any CRC available. Flash starts on `0x80000000` and `0x80040000` (2 banks for bootloader and main program). Currently I assuming If 0x80040004 is between `0x80040000` and `0x80080000`, program is flashed. But how can I check if program is valid? I can't find where is size of binary that should be written on flash, so I can check last few integers.

Here is first few bytes from BIN (sorry, can't post whole file): 
[image]
Last byte that is not programmed is `0x80051C00` (program has 72704 bytes).

Comment: I am not sure that the file content is at all useful, but do not post off-site links to question content,

Comment: checking the last few doesnt insure the ones in between were correct.  You either have to do this on the loader end with a verify or runtime with adding something to the binary, wrapping/padding the end with fill and then a checksum/crc in there.  runtime startup code would then check the whole space.  or the prior option something from the host when it programs the mcu then does a read back and verifies....or both.

Comment: This Application Note [AN277](http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/an277.pdf) may give you an idea about how to add a CRC to your binary image.  (The example uses Keil tools but it can be adapted to other tool chains.)

Comment: I added, but still I want to be sure program is valid. I guess I'll flash first KiB at the end, that way I'll avoid situation in which I have programmed half of program, but not end of the program. Checking update is in most times useless and energy draining activity. I'll write a bootloop protection that will check update only if program crashed before it check update manually or it was requested.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely error is loss of data connection during the transfer so that the image is only partially written.  The chances of programming error once the data is received is probably negligible, although your transfer protocol should include some sort of data integrity check.  For that you could simply validate the checksum of hex-file records or use a protocol with CRC error checking such as XMODEM-CRC or XMODEM-1K.

Ensuring that you do not attempt to start a partially loaded application image is simple.  It is not necessary to program the flash in address order or even the order the data arrives in. Given that, when the data for the reset-vector at `0x80040004` is received, you retain it in RAM and program it last.  That way the reset vector value will always be 0xFFFFFFFF if the programming did not complete:

Pseudo-code:

```
WHILE receiving data

    IF program_address in range
        // Write all data except address at reset vector
        IF program_address == 0x80040004
            start_address = program_data
        ELSE
            write( program_address, program_data )
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDWHILE

// Write reset vector *LAST*
write( 0x80040004, start_address )
```

Then in the start-up code:

```
IF @0x80040004 == 0xFFFFFFFFFF
    NO APPLICATION - DO SOMETHING!
ELSE
    START APPLICATION
ENDIF
```

Comment: @Razi91 : But that is not what you have described in your question.  What is it about this solution that is unsatisfactory.  It is robust.